# How to implement an interface?

Tags: java, interface, code-organization

I'm very new to java and to get my feet a little wet I'm trying to build a simple budget program for my wife and me.  I have quite a few classes, which I'm still learning to organize, but my primary question for this thread is with regards to my interface.

It looks like this:

```
package com.budgeter;

public interface Category {

void setPersonalLoan(int budget);
void setDonationsGifts(int budget);
void setRecreation(int budget);
void setHouseHoldItems(int budget);
void setUtilities(int budget);
void setSavings(int budget);
void setGroceries(int budget);
void setAutoInsurance(int budget);
void setAutoPayment(int budget);
void setHomeInsurance(int budget);
void setHomePayment(int budget);

}
```

I have no idea if this interface is done according to a best practice or not, but my goal is to have a way to have a defined set of categories.  Next, I have another class called `BillCategory` which I can use to add a custom category.  Again, not sure if this is a correct way of using an interface.

So I'm using this interface this way:

```
package com.budgeter;

public class Bills implements Category {

private Double amount;
private Double totalBills;

public Bills() {}
public Bills(double amount) {
    setTotal(amount);
}

private void setTotal(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
    totalBills = amount;
}

public Double getTotal() {
    return totalBills;
}
@Override
public void setPersonalLoan(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setDonationsGifts(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setRecreation(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setHouseHoldItems(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setUtilities(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setSavings(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setGroceries(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setAutoInsurance(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setAutoPayment(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setHomeInsurance(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setHomePayment(int budget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here is my `BillCategory` class which I use to add a new category, but not completely sure how to relate this to my interface:

```
package com.budgeter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BillCategory {

private static Map<String, Integer> categories = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void addCategory(String categoryName, int frequency) {
    categories.put(categoryName, frequency);
}

public Map<String, Integer> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

}
```

- What is the most effective way to check if an item was set and then calculate all of them for my `getTotal()` method?
- Am I using an interface properly?
- Am I using a good naming convention (e.g. Category)?
- The `setTotalAmount()` method I wasn't sure if I should pass a reference to `amount` or set the `amount` using `this.amount = amount` and then access it globally.  Is there a best practice for this?
- What is the best way to relate my `BillCategory` class to the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I would suggest for your interface would be to add some sort of visibility `(public, private, protected)` to your method declarations.  You have that in the implementation but not in the interface.  The code in the implementation looks fine, just the two variables seem to be doing the same thing.  I do not know if I fully understand why you called it Category but having upper case Interface names is fine convention in java.

In set methods you can do exactly what you did `this.amount = amount`, calling that method from the constructor is fine practice.

In regards to your first question if you add a class variable for each of your set methods and just set that variable to the value passed in then you can add up the total in the `getTotal()` method and return that value.

```
private int personalLoan;
private int donationGifts;
private int recreation;
private int houseHoldItems;
...

@Override
public void setPersonalLoan(int budget) {
    this.personalLoan = budget;
}
@Override
public void setDonationsGifts(int budget) {
    this.donationGifts = budget;
}
@Override
public void setRecreation(int budget) {
    this.recreation = budget;
}
@Override
public void setHouseHoldItems(int budget) {
    this.houseHoldItems = budget;
}
...


public double getTotal() {
    double total = personalLoan + donationGifts + recreation + houseHoldItems + utilities + savings + groceries....
    return total;
}
```

You can also have all of those variables as parameters in your constructor and set them using those methods instead of taking in one value for your total.

Note I did catch that you have your budgets as `int's` as such you cannot have decimal values for your budget.  You may want to change that in your interface and then returning a double for the `getTotal()` makes more sense.

Comment: What would recommend naming the interface?  And could you give me an example for your last paragraph?  Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: If the Category name makes sense to you then keep it that way, just remember Interfaces are supposed to be generic and implemented multiple times.  So if you are going to use another implementation of it and both that Class and Bills are both a Category then it works perfect.  I will throw some more code up there for an example of the last part.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to name the interface since I also have another class (not shown) named `BillCategory` which I use to `addCategory()`. I assume `BillCategory` would be a better name for the interface?

Comment: hmm... I guess I could also create a Map and add the int values to a map and then total the value of the Map via a loop.

Comment: I am not completely sure how your BillCategory class works but just for reference you can make a `Map` of Category like `Map<String, Category>` and then you can call `.put("key",bills)` or any other implementation of Category in the map and retrieve them by the key.

Comment: You can also do what you just said prior to my last comment, that would work fine if you need to reference the categories by a String name.